# Preprocess GET/POST Data From Apache/JBoss

Tags: java, apache, post, web, jboss

Is there a way to access GET/POST data before it is passed to a JBoss application, perhaps in the web serving environment? I'd like to perform some simple data cleaning prior to passing it to the JBoss app I have inherited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use filters (requires Servlet specification version 2.3).

The following links might help you and you can search more.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm

http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/servlet-filterlistener/

http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/how-to-write-a-simple-servlet-filter/